# Windows Forms in LINQPad Command Line vs LINQPad Proper

Tags: c#, winforms, linqpad

I have a script I run via `lprun.exe` that appears different than when it is ran via LINQPad proper.  When I run via command line, it appears as so:

[image]

- Note the overlap of checkboxes in the 'Production Publish Settings' and the checkbox with the Cancel button.

When I run it from LINQPad proper, it shows up as so:

[image]

- Note that there is no overlap and the font looks crisper and spacing is 'better'.

Is there some setting on lprun command to make it look the same as when ran in LINQPad proper?

**Update**

Due to my lack of knowledge on scaling/Windows Forms, could these lines (which I just grabbed from the Form Designer originally from Visual Studio before moving code into my script) be causing issue?

```
this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(750, 450);
this.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(765, 480);
```

Comment: It seems to me that both forms have a slighty different size, which can cause rearrangment of controls. Do you have specified any initial size for it?

Comment: See update.  But both are running the same *.linq script.  So same code runs in each scenario.

Comment: Just a guess, but given that both forms have a different form and the scale mode is set to the font, there is a chance that Linqpad itself is messing with the initial font, hence different scaling, hence different sizes, which the command-line version hasn't, as it has no GUI. Of course the real test is to run the real executable from Visual Studio.

Comment: The first image shows a non-DpiAware application, hence System-scaled. The other one shows that the app is not scaled or DpiAware (the System doesn't *virtualize* it). -- The presentation of a non-DpiAware app that scales to Font is *unpredictable* (unless you design for this explicitly, using nested container and such - still kind of difficult to predict what it will look like in some scaled Screens, needs **a lot** of testing -- Too much *entropy*, IMO).

Comment: Have you tried calling Application.SetHighDpiMode(HighDpiMode.SystemAware) in the script?

Comment: Hmm, I have a reference to System.Windows.Forms obviously (v 4.30319) and that method isn't available.  Guess I could reference different version of System.Windows.Forms or move script to upgraded LINQPad, unless there is another way to do this in v4*?

Comment: The method @JoeAlbahari is referring to is available from .Net 5+, it's usually called in Program.cs, since you need to call it before any Window has a Handle. In a .Net Framework 4.8 app (I don't even consider .Net Framework versions prior to 4.8), use set the DpiAwareness mode in `App.config`. -- I suggest the `PerMonitorV2` mode, not `SystemAware`. -- See, e.g., [High DPI Desktop Application Development on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/high-dpi-desktop-application-development-on-windows)

Comment: But with a LINQPad script, is there such thing as `app.config`?